# C macro gsl library code conversion to D

Tags: c, macros, d, c-preprocessor

I am doing a code conversion from C header file in the gsl numeric library to D under linux ubuntu. I would like to know what the macros:

```
/* 1 */ #define GSL_VAR extern // gsl types.h file
/* 2 */ #define GSL_RANGE_COND(x) (x) // gsl_inline.h file
/* 3 */ #define GSL_FN_EVAL(F,x) (*((F)->function))(x,(F)->params)
```

do.

I suspect that GSL_VAR in particular has been causing me some issues. An example of its use is

```
GSL_VAR const gsl_rng_type *gsl_rng_borosh13; //gsl_rng.h
```

which I convert to

```
gsl_rng_borosh13 const(gsl_rng_type)*; // D Code
```

Is this the correct thing to do?

Comment: Can you provide a sample usage of the second one? Maybe from the corresponding *.c* file.

Comment: if (GSL_RANGE_COND(1)) {...} // gsl_matrix_complex_double.h

Comment: hmm looks like a predicate to maybe alias GSL_RANGE_COND = bool function(int x)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* 1 */ #define GSL_VAR extern // gsl types.h file
```

If you're converting C code to D, this can be dropped entirely, since D uses modules. If you're writing bindings, then you should use `extern(C)`.

```
/* 2 */ #define GSL_RANGE_COND(x) (x) // gsl_inline.h file
```

This is the identity function. In D, you would write a function instead of using a macro (ex. `int GSL_RANGE_COND(int x) { return x; }`). However, I imagine that compile-time flags would alter the behavior of this macro; in D, you would use `version` statements.

```
/* 3 */ #define GSL_FN_EVAL(F,x) (*((F)->function))(x,(F)->params)
```

Again, in D you would write a function for this. Replace `T`, `U`, and `V`. with the correct types.

```
T GSL_FN_EVAL(U* F, V x) { return F.function(x, F.params); }
```

Comment: Interesting. It looks as if the preprocessor in C allows you to get away without specifying return and argument types. Is this true? I guess D has templates but C's preprocessor technique looks very interesting.

Comment: @DataPulverizer Since its just textual substitution, the processor has no concept of types. This actually makes it pretty dangerous; D functions/templates provide most of the features of macros while also adding type safety.

Comment: Just remembered that D has mixins https://dlang.org/mixin.html which are similar functionality to C preprocessor.